# problem to get the Referer page

Tags: tcl, http-referer, referer, openacs

I'm trying to get the referer page, but i have a problem , sometimes i get bad the referer page, 
for example:

i have 3 pages, when the page 1 link to page 2 , and the page 2 make a process and after redirect to page 3, so when i try to get the referer page in the page 3, i get the page 1 and not the page 2,

I think that the problem is the page 2 this page doesn´t show anything to the user, is only a page who make a procedure.

Do you have any idea how i can to get the referer page correctly??

Thanks.

I'm using TCL with openacs

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET, VB.NET or PHP?

Comment: But if you try to get it doing what you want, won't it go into some kind of loop?  If page 2 redirects to page 3, which then redirects back to page 2 etc etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are you sending the user from page 2 to page 3? with php:

`enter code here`header("location:")

or html redirect?
if you are using header("location:") it will probably not work. try using html redirect like

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=page3">
```

Comment: well i'm using TCL, OPENACS, and to redirect I do this   
<br>
ad_returnredirect $url
<br>
but i don't know if that could be the reason to my problem :P becasuse when i redirect to another page, who show something to the user i dont have thar problem, with that instruction

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without knowing exactly what you're trying to do. If page 2 is only calling a procedure, what about putting the contents of page 2 into an **ad_proc**, and then calling that proc in page 3? Or can page 2 redirect to other places when it is finished?

If you give more info, I'm sure I can help. The normal way I would pass referer info in OpenACS is to use a variable called **return_url**, which I pass from one page to the next as a hidden form element. There are lots of examples of that in OpenACS. Alternatively you could use **ad_set_client_property** to store it on page 1 and then on page 3 use **ad_get_client_property** to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone,

I already solve my problem using the < meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=page3" >, but in openacs there is a function that do it.

I relplace the

```
       ad_returnredirect
```

by

```
       util_ReturnMetaRefresh
```

so in this way i already can read the correct referer page